# How to encrypt and decrypt json file in a Google Map

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, encryption, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a json file to store the data from my markers and send it to a Google Map using the v3 version. Unfortunately, my entries (more than 14.000+) are displayed in this json file and **I need to encrypt that data** in order to not show the content of the file to the user, because I don't want some users to copy my entries information.

How can I do that? At the moment, that's my code (without encrypt):

I have searched a lot throught Google but it don't seem to exist anythting for my situation.

**GoogleMap.php**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="data.json"></script>
<script>
var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/markerclusterer';
if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
script += '_compiled';
}
script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
document.write(script);
</script>
```

In my **data.json** is stored all the information regarding my entries (name, latitude, longitude...).

Comment: Use HTTPS. There is no other way to protect your data in transit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obfuscate your data, but you cannot encrypt it with the objective to preserve confidentiality. When the client browser receives the encrypted data, the browser will have to have a way to decrypt the data so that the maps API can consume the data. For this to work the key will also need to be present on the client. So the user will be able to decrypt it with enough effort (not brute-force, but combining the data). If the data can be decrypted then this is simply an obfuscation technique.

This can only work with symmetric ciphers such as AES. You can use for example [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).

Comment: See also: [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/)